# How to calculate Frame Per Second in opencv?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, frame-rate, gcc4.9

Here is my code it display video but at high fps. I want original fps here but don't know how to do it. Watching some tutorials , they are using `VideoCapture` , I tried to use it but this is giving me linker error `undefined reference to 'cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(std::string const&)'..` though I am linking all libraries but error is same. I am using `Dev-C++ 5.11 (GCC 4.9.2)` , so any idea how to use `(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)`here -

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
   double fps=0;
   cvNamedWindow( "Movie", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );
   CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "G:\\movie\\Journey.2.The.Mysterious.Island.2012.avi" );
   IplImage* frame;

   //cv::VideoCapture cap("G:\\movie\\Journey.2.The.Mysterious.Island.2012.avi" ); [giving me error]
   //fps=cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); [How to use this]

   while(1)
   {
       frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
       if( !frame ) break;
       cvShowImage( "Movie", frame );
       char c = cvWaitKey(27);
       if( c == 27 ) break; //esc
   }
   cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
   cvDestroyWindow( "Movie" );
}
```

Thnx :)

Comment: what opencv version?

Comment: @Miki Version 2.4.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double fps=cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

Comment: @uditr043 I'm glad. However, you shold consider using the new C++ syntax, starting by including `#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"` and "basically" removing _cv_ in front of the functions and classes...

Comment: Okay , i will follow this , thnx :)